# Best practice on using async / await

Tags: c#, async-await

Say I have the following class definitions:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public CalculatorResult Calculate()
    {
        return LongRunningCalculation();
    }

    private CalculatorResult LongRunningCalculation()
    {
        return new CalculatorResult(0.00);
    }
}

public class ClassThatUsesACalculator
{
    private readonly Calculator calculator;

    public ClassThatUsesACalculator()
    {
        this.calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var result = calculator.Calculate();

            DoSomethingWithCalculationResult(result);

            DoLightWork();

            OnProgressChanged();
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form : Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoWork();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        var calculator = new ClassThatUsesACalculator();
        calculator.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Update progressbar
        };

        calculator.DoWork();
    }
}
```

If I would want to do the work done in `DoWork()`, on the form, asynchronously I could add a method (`GetCalculationTask`) that returns a task using `Task.Run()` and add a async eventhandler i.e. For a button (`MethodOne`).

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that this would be the only option when the `ClassThatUsesACalculator` and `Calculator` classes reside in a library I don't own.

```
private Task GetCalculationTask(IProgress<CalculatorProgress> progress)
{
    var calculator = new ClassThatUsesACalculator();
    calculator.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        progress.Report(new CalculatorProgress(0));
    };

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        calculator.DoWork();
    });
}

private async void MethodOne(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<CalculatorProgress> progress = new Progress<CalculatorProgress>   (UpdateProgressBar);

    await GetCalculationTask(progress);
}
```

In the case I do own the library I think there are two more options, one of which very much like the first one. Probably due to the lack of my own understanding.

Create a method on on `ClassThatUsesACalculator` that encapsulates the `DoWork()` method and then call that from an asynchronous method on the form.

or,

1. Encapsulate the `LongRunningCalculation()` on the `Calculator` class with a `Task.Run()`.

   ```
   public Task<CalculatorResult> CalculateAsync()
   {
       return Task.Run(() =>
       {
           return LongRunningCalculation();
       });
   }
   ```
2. Create an async method on `ClassThatUsesACalculator` the calls that awaits the newly created method.

   ```
   public async Task DoWorkAsync()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           var result = await calculator.CalculateAsync();

           DoSomethingWithCalculationResult(result);

           DoLightWork();

           OnProgressChanged(); 
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an asynchronous method on the form (`MethodThree`)

   ```
   private async void MethodThree(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       IProgress<CalculatorProgress> progress = new Progress<CalculatorProgress>(UpdateProgressBar);

       var calculator = new ClassThatUsesACalculator();
       calculator.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
       {
           progress.Report(new CalculatorProgress(0));
       };

       await calculator.DoWorkAsync();
   }
   ```

Now, in my opinion the last option would be the best as I would remain more control. But maybe I'm way off and would like someone's opinion or pointers on this as I can only find explanations on how to consume async, but never really how to build methods for others to consume.

Comment: Your question is really long and overly wordy-it might help if you narrow it down to concisely explain what you want to know. By the way, for quick stuff, `async` isn't really necessary. `async` is great for I/O tasks like accessing a file, database, or web service. But the overhead for running quick bits of non-I/O code might actually decrease performance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a general rule, push any `Task.Run` usage as far up the call stack as possible.

What you want to *avoid* is having a method with an asynchronous signature that is implemented using `Task.Run` in a reusable component. That's a lying API. I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) that goes into greater detail.

If you control the classes in question, I recommend using `IProgress<T>` instead of events for progress updates. `IProgress<T>` works just fine with synchronous code as well as asynchronous:

```
public void DoWork(IProgress<CalculatorProgress> progress = null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    var result = calculator.Calculate();

    DoSomethingWithCalculationResult(result);

    DoLightWork();

    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(new CalculatorProgress(...));
  }
}
```

Then using it is quite straightforward:

```
private async void MethodTwo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IProgress<CalculatorProgress> progress = new Progress<CalculatorProgress>(UpdateProgressBar);

  var calculator = new ClassThatUsesACalculator();

  await Task.Run(() => calculator.DoWork(progress));
}
```

That keeps the `Task.Run` usage in the component that needs it - the UI layer - and out of the business logic.

Comment: This should be sung from the mountain tops.